# Get product custom attribute in observer that listens to x specific event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-attributes

Anyone know how to get product custom attribute in observer? In  my case event is controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add.

My current code is giving me:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProduct() on null in

```
 $product = $this->productRepository->getById($observer->getItem()->getProduct()->getId());
        $attr = $product->getData('product_customattribute');
```

Also I tried this (same error):

```
 $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
   $attr = $product->getProduct()->getAttributeText('product_customattribute');
```

**UPDATE**

My module redirect after click add to cart (with adding to the cart)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="myvendor_mymodule_observer_redirect" instance="MyVendor\MyModule\Observer\Redirect" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and my Observer

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
//use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;
//use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Redirect implements  \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;
    protected $resultRedirect;

    public function __construct(
    //    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
    //    StoreManager $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
    )
    {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
       // $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
      //  $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $url = 'https://domain.com/url.html';
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    }
}
```

I want change $url  with custom attribute.
I was able to get product data using **catalog_product_save_after** but redirect wasn't working. Maybe I could connect somehow this two observers.

**UPDATE 2**

On this event I get custom attribute

> checkout_cart_add_product_complete

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute');
       $this->_logger->log(100,print_r( $customAttribute, true));
}
```

On this I get redirect after add to cart

> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
          $url = '/cart';  //should be custom_attribute

            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
}
```

But I can get this values in one observer. I tried to connect them but not sure what should I use? Cache? register? to pass data from one observer to another.

Comment: Which event you have tried to observe?

Comment: I use controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get this done with customer session storage

On this event I get custom attribute and save it on customer session

> checkout_cart_add_product_complete

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    // get product custom attribute
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute');

    // store attribute in customer session
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    $myArray = $customAttribute->getValue();
    $setValue = $this->customerSession->setMyValue($myArray);
}
```

On this I get redirect after add to cart and take attribute from customer session

> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    // get Value from customer session
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); //Get customer object
    $newurl = $this->customerSession->getMyValue();

    //set redirect from attribute
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($newurl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are listening on `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` you have the following items on the `$observer`

```
 ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
```

Your code should look smth like this

```
$product = $observer->getProduct(); // or $observer->getData('product');
$customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
// to avoid errors double check that this product 
// has the custom attribute associated to it
$value = $customAttribute !== null ? $customAttribute->getValue() : null;
```

It's also a good practice to use the debugger to see what is what and what properties and values are available on a given object.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

**EDIT** as result of the comment

You do not have the product loaded at that point. You only have the controller instance and the request as it can be seen `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::dispatch()`. You must have smth on the request like a `product_id` or `product_sku`.

In a development environment if you don't have **xdebug**(you should really take care of that, it pays off) the fastest way to debug stuff is `var_dump($object->getData())`.

On this specific event what you can do is inject the product repository in the constructor, get the product id from the request and load the product.

smth like

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($observer->getRequest()->getProductId())
```

Once you have the product above should apply. You can add some extra checks like, is there a request on the observer data? is there a product id on the request and so on.

Comment: Sorry I use controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add my mistake. How  You check what item do You have in $observer?  Curentlly I use $this->_logger->log(100,print_r( $value, true));  WIth Xdebug have some problems for different Question.

Comment: Oh ok I found this in file  $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );
Problem that I cannot find mine event

Comment: Check edited answer please.

Comment: I would also edit the question to be smth like. Get product custom attribute in observer that listens to x specific event. You might get more hits. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for ideas. This I tried before getById. I see with var_dumb there is my attribute   protected 'extensionAttributes' => null
      protected 'customAttributeFactory' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory)[292]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager)[43]
              ...
      protected 'customAttributesCodes' => null
      ...
      protected '_origData' => 
        array (size=75) 'my_attribute' => string ' value'

Comment: Yesterday somehow I get attributes with var_dump, today I cant. Maybe I can use two events, on one grab  product attribute and on second use this data?

Comment: I updated my Question